# How iPad screen gameplay is captured?

Tags: ipad, screen-capture

In some video such as

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csjXiu9HLrA

I see that it looks like the iPad video is captured... but it is also said that the Component cable for iPad only works for movies and photos, but not for apps...  so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment, the Simulator probably is not it...  I have heard using the VGA adaptor and using a VGA to computer file recorder box that can hook up VGA output to a computer's USB port and record the VGA signal... maybe that's it...  I wonder if this is how the "white dot" is recorded.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely the video was captured using the iOS development emulator rather than the actual iPad itself.

Comment: I thought you cannot use the Simulator to play those 3rd party apps -- the Simulator is only for testing your own development.  It is not an emulator in the sense that it cannot run compiled code of the 3rd party, but it must compile the code differently (into Intel machine code) to work with the simulator.  All third party code are compiled to ARM machine code.